# Making pagination meta fields in Laravel snake case

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to transform Laravel's pagination response `meta` field into `camelCase` globally to the application.

From

```
{
  "data": [
    ...
  ],
  "links": {
    "first": "http://localhost:8081/todo?page=1",
    "last": "http://localhost:8081/todo?page=2",
    "prev": null,
    "next": "http://localhost:8081/todo?page=2"
  },
  "meta": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "last_page": 2,
    ...
  }
}
```

to

```
{
  "data": [
    ...
  ],
  "links": {
    "first": "http://localhost:8081/todo?page=1",
    "last": "http://localhost:8081/todo?page=2",
    "prev": null,
    "next": "http://localhost:8081/todo?page=2"
  },
  "meta": {
    "currentCage": 1,
    "lastPage": 2,
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm using Laravel Resources so I know I can do for each resource something like:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'data' => $this->collection,
        'meta' => [
            'currentPage' => $this->currentPage(),
            'perPage' => $this->perPage(),
        ],
    ];
}
```

but this would required to either:

1. Create a Trait to provide this conversion from `snake_case` to `camelCase`
2. Have to defined in every ResourceCollection this conversion

Is there a global way to modify this response being returned when we are paginating a resource?

Comment: I don't think of an easy way to do this.. you may use your own class and override the metadata and every resource would extend from ur new class

Comment: So you want to globally change the definition of your ResourceCollections? Just edit them all.

Comment: I think best way is to store `meta` in a temp variable, loop over  variable and then replace `meta` with new keys

Comment: Why would you like to do so ? There is not an easy or clean solution for this. If you just don't like the `snake_case` then you would better stick to it in your JS or who ever is getting this info, as changing this is way more horrible than trying to read `current_page` instead of `currentPage`...

Comment: @matiaslauriti maintain a good approach in my code base. Everything that goes out the API is `camelCased` and having everything structured as such is a nice thing in my opinion. But then again, this is opinion based and this is not what the original question was aimed at

Comment: @Charlie Yeah, I understand your point, but laravel loves to do `snake_case` for this sort of things, so you should morph to what they like as doing the change you want is way more difficult and "horrible" and staying with lower case. Also, it is no problem for you to change this on the receiving side, who ever consumes your API should have a Mapper layer that will do this transform and problem solved... not more your API problem.